# Select for update query returns cardinality violation

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, locking, database-concurrency, postgres-9.6

We are running this query in Postgres 9.6.10 in a Google managed cloud DB:

```
WITH update AS
  (UPDATE cart SET loyalty = loyalty || jsonb_insert('{}', '{coupon}', loyalty#>'{scan_coupon}' || $1) WHERE id = 
  (SELECT id FROM cart WHERE id = $2 AND status = $3 and item_version = $4 FOR UPDATE) returning *)
SELECT * FROM updated
```

`cart` is a table that has `id` as the primary key. `loyalty` is a jsonb column and `item_version` is a function that increments on some operations but several updates are expected to take place before `item_version` is updated. `status` is an enumerated type.

Under highly concurrent updates we rarely get the following error:

```
Cardinality_violation, file: "nodeSubplan.c", line: "1127", message: "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression", pg_code: "21000", routine: "ExecSetParamPlan", severity: "ERROR", unknown: "ERROR"
```

I've confirmed that `$2` is actually an integer and points to an existing row and since `id` is the primary key I don't see how this could ever return more than one row.

Is it the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` that is the offending query? How could that query return more than one row if `id` is the primary key.

Comment: `WITH update` is supposed to be `WITH updated` I assume.

Comment: What is your Postgres version? There have been some bugs which could lead to corrupted unique indexes allowing duplicate values.

Comment: The postgres version is 9.6.

Comment: The point release would be relevant to see the patch level: 9.6.???

Comment: 9.6.10 It's Google managed Cloud SQL.

Comment: [9.6.13 is current as of writing.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Google is a bit behind. Wouldn't know of any bugs affecting UNIQUE indexes in that version, though. Maybe @a_horse knows more?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: 9.6.10 or .13 should be fine - it was just a wild guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can simplify to:

```
UPDATE cart
SET    loyalty = loyalty || jsonb_build_object('coupon', loyalty->'scan_coupon') || $1
WHERE  id  =  $2
AND    status = $3
AND    item_version = $4
RETURNING *;
```

The `UPDATE` locks the row in just the same way as your nested `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` would.

And [`jsonb_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) is simpler, doing the same as your `jsonb_insert()`. Or maybe simpler, yet:

```
SET    loyalty = jsonb_insert(loyalty, '{coupon}', loyalty->'scan_coupon') || $1
```

I am just as surprised as you are, that the subquery (you don't need) would return more than one row somehow. Seems impossible. Are you sure that's the source of the error message?

Comment: I'll try this and see if I can reproduce it. It's a little difficult to reproduce it, but I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: We've wrapped it in a `WITH` because it wasn't returning the most up-to-date `loyalty` column when doing highly concurrent writes to that column. I'm not sure why we're using a subquery instead of where directly.

Comment: The CTE wrapper (`WITH ...`) should not have any bearing whatsoever on the  returned column, which is the same either way. That's also very odd. You might try my simplified version and see if the problems persist.

Comment: I've used you're version and cannot reproduce the same issue. Which solves my real problem. Thanks.